# Jquery Ajax Load Cache

Tags: jquery, ajax

I believe my load method is sometimes caching and I want to disable this.

I'm currently using:

```
function getClient(date, appId) {

    $("#cPlaceholder").load("/GetClient?id=" + appId+",
                 function () {
                     $('#clientModal').modal('show');
                 });
    }
```

But I've read that I should use ajaxSetup so changed to..

```
function getClient(date, appId) {
 $.ajaxSetup ({
            url:"/GetClient?id=" + appId+",
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
               ("#cPlaceholder").html(result);
                $('#cPlaceholder').modal('show');
            }
        });
}
```

But this does not seem to execute?
Any ideas?

Comment: Any logs in console ? in XHR request you see them ?

Answer (score 1):

Change it back to just ajax;

```
 $.ajax ({
            url:"/GetClient?id=" + appId,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                $("#cPlaceholder").html(result);
                $('#cPlaceholder').modal('show');
            }
        });
```

Ajaxsetup does it globally so you could first run;

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Then your load() call. But Ajaxsetup does not **replace** the ajax call it just sets the defaults to be used in future ones.

P.S. You also have two typos;

```
url:"/GetClient?id=" + appId+",
```

should not have the last quote;

```
url:"/GetClient?id=" + appId,
```

and

```
("#cPlaceholder").html(result);
```

is missing the $

```
$("#cPlaceholder").html(result);
```

Comment: Hey, should I put this just in the script section? ie <script> $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });</script>

Comment: @D-W That is indeed where it would go, BEFORE the actual ajax call. However I highly recommend using the cache: false inside the individual ajax call instead, because if you later add another ajax call to the page and DO want it to use the cache, this will prevent that from happening. Best to be explicit...

Comment: @D-W Also check your typos